# How can I edit the Contents in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Hi
I would like to make an analog window New Project of Visual Studio 2010, for my program.
I want to edit the name of the item by double-clicking the mouse. 
Example in the picture.
P.S. sorry for my bad english

http://img822.imageshack.us/i/20699396.png/

Comment: Which part of this are you having problems with?  Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 1):

Check out codeproject.com's [Editable TextBlock in WPF for In-place Editing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/editabletextblock.aspx)